# const_cast with bool: if condition ignored

Tags: c++, visual-c++, casting, boolean, constants

VC++ 2010 problem:

```
const bool bNew = true;
const_cast<bool&>(bNew) = false;
if(bNew)//bNew is false here, but
{
    int i = 0;//this line will be executed
}
```

Why?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add a tag for VC++ 2010?

Comment: @C-Otto: done, thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the compiler has optimized the evaluation of `bNew` to `true` regardless of what you do in the second line.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is UB.

Comment: As `bNew` was declared const, casting away the const is Undefined Behaviour and reasoning about subsequent lines meaningless. _" Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior."_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast

Comment: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633)

Answer (score 3):

From section 7.1.5.1/4 of the C++03 standard:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const` object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior.

You declared `bNew` to be a `const` object, then you undermined the type system by explicitly casting it away to modify it.  You therefore invoked *undefined behavior*, which means that *anything* can happen.

Comment: So, what is purpose of const_cast?

Comment: When you're 100% sure the object wasn't created const. Avoid it.

Comment: @AcaMiln: Mainly dealing with bad or ancient APIs which are themselves not const-correct. For example, say you need to call a function which accepts a `MyClass& obj` argument, yet you know that this function does not modify `obj`; it just lacks the `const` in the reference. Now you've got a `MyClass const arg` you need to pass to that function. This is where a `const_cast` would be appropriate.

Comment: @Ven: Not true. See my example.

Comment: that's just awful

Comment: @Ven For C APIs, sometimes functions cannot be `const`-correct.  For example, suppose you are invoking a function `f` that takes as arguments a callback and a pointer to caller-specified callback data. `f` does not know or care what the callback does with its data. `f` could declare the callback data as `const void*`, but that either would impose unnecessary restrictions on the callback or would be misleading.  Meanwhile, callers of `f` should be allowed to supply `const T*` for the callback data if they know that the callback won't change it.